# Phonegap Facebook Connection can not find JavaScript

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know there are a few articles discussing this issue, I followed them all with no luck.

I am getting the ever issue - "Facebook variable does not exist. check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file"

My bundle name in Xcode is `org.apache.cordova.Game`

So if I understood correctly in my config file I wrote:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.Game.plugins.FacebookConnectPlugin">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="123123" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Game" />
</gap:plugin>
```

I am trying to launch the sample `index.html` and the `cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js` and `facebook-js-sdk.js` are both in `www` folder (copied the `js` using finder and no action from Xcode)

`index.html` copied to `www` in finder as well and the source is :

```
<body>
    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
    <button onclick="me()">Me</button>
    <!--<button onclick="getSession()">Get session</button>-->
    <button onclick="getLoginStatus()">Get login</button>
    <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
    <button onclick="facebookWallPost()">facebookWallPost</button>
    <button onclick="publishStoryFriend()">friendstory</button>

    <div id="data">loading ...</div>

    <!--<script src="http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>-->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <!-- cordova -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
    <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
    <!-- facebook js sdk -->
    <script src="facebook_js_sdk.js"></script>

    <script>
.........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all from cordova 3 the one should add the the config file the plugin as feature and not as plugin

```
    <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
       <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
```

Second of all in the html it should be on device ready and not as documented in the web dev API by FB:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                          try {

                          FB.init({ appId: "12345", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });


                          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                                             getProfile();
                        });


                          } catch (e) {
                          alert(e);
                          }
                          }, false);
```